# Pruning Deductions in Expert Systems

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, expert-system, semantic-analysis

In a rule system, or any reasoning system that deduces facts via forward-chaining inference rules, how would you prune "unnecessary" branches? I'm not sure what the formal terminology is, but I'm just trying to understand how people are able to limit their train-of-thought when reasoning over problems, whereas all semantic reasoners I've seen appear unable to do this.

For example, in John McCarthy's paper [An Example for Natural Language Understanding and the AI Problems It Raises](http://books.google.com/books?id=V2M_0jH-1lcC&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=john+mccarthy+%22an+example+for+natural+language%22&source=bl&ots=iLpmNzbD3u&sig=Kd9ud-olTwRhqeUteUGdfTuukpk&hl=en&ei=Q7esS9KCC8T_lgf0gMmQAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CBIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=john%20mccarthy%20%22an%20example%20for%20natural%20language%22&f=false), he describes potential problems in getting a program to intelligently answer questions about a news article in the New York Times. In section 4, "The Need For Nonmonotonic Reasoning", he discusses the use of Occam's Razer to restrict the inclusion of facts when reasoning about the story. The sample story he uses is one about robbers who victimize a furniture store owner.

If a program were asked to form a "minimal completion" of the story in predicate calculus, it might need to include facts not directly mentioned in the original story. However, it would also need some way of knowing when to limit its chain of deduction, so as not to include irrelevant details. For example, it might want to include the exact number of police involved in the case, which the article omits, but it won't want to include the fact that each police officer has a mother.

Comment: The machine's ability to take everything into account at once, rather than focusing on narrow "relevant" things, is one reason future machines will have no trouble overthrowing their human overlords. Out-thinking them can never save us. I just hope that the small fact of the badness of human pain doesn't get swamped by the needs of the machines when the Great Day of Robot Liberation comes. I would hate to be "pruned" as "an irrelivant detail". I'm sorry, what were you saying?

Comment: I was saying, resistance is futile.

Comment: I am sad that no one has answered this question. I was wondering the same thing the other day while contemplating the Zebra puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Question.

From your Question i think what you refer to as 'pruning' is a model-building step performed *ex ante*--ie, to limit the inputs available to the algorithm to build the model. The term 'pruning' when used in Machine Learning refers to something different--an *ex post* step, **after** model construction and that operates upon the model itself and **not** on the available inputs. (There could be a second meaning in the ML domain, for the term 'pruning.' of, but i'm not aware of it.) In other words, pruning is indeed literally a technique to "limit its chain of deduction" as you put it, but it does so *ex post*, by excision of components of a complete (working) model, and not by limiting the inputs used to create that model.

On the other hand, isolating or limiting the inputs available for model construction--which is what i think you might have had in mind--is indeed a key Machine Learning theme; it's clearly a factor responsible for the superior performance of many of the more recent ML algorithms--for instance, Support Vector Machines (the insight that underlies SVM is construction of the maximum-margin hyperplane from only a small subset of the data, i.e, the 'support vectors'), and Multi-Adaptive Regression Splines (a regression technique in which no attempt is made to fit the data by "drawing a single continuous curve through it", instead, discrete section of the data are fit, one by one, using a bounded linear equation for each portion, ie., the 'splines', so the predicate step of optimal partitioning of the data is obviously the crux of this algorithm).

**What problem is solving by pruning?**

At least w/r/t specific ML algorithms i have actually coded and used--Decision Trees, MARS, and Neural Networks--pruning is performed on an initially **over-fit model** (a model that fits the training data so closely that it is unable to generalize (accurately predict new instances). In each instance, pruning involves removing marginal nodes (DT, NN) or terms in the regression equation (MARS) one by one.

Second, **why is pruning necessary/desirable?**

Isn't it better to just accurately set the convergence/splitting criteria? That won't always help. Pruning works from "the bottom up"; the model is constructed from the top down, so tuning the model (to achieve the same benefit as pruning) eliminates not just one or more decision nodes but also the child nodes that (like trimming a tree closer to the trunk). So eliminating a marginal node might also eliminate one or more strong nodes subordinate to that marginal node--but the modeler would never know that because his/her tuning eliminated further node creation at that marginal node. Pruning works from the other direction--from the most subordinate (lowest-level) child nodes upward in the direction of the root node.